# Is this a bug or intended design of FireFox?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, web-applications

In FireFox, using JavaScript, when a user presses enter to select "ok" on an alert Window the `onkeyup` get fired. In Internet Explore this does not happen.

This HTML code demonstrates what I'm saying. Open it, type a character in the text field and select "ok" by pressing enter. Try it in FireFox and IE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>JS example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function popup()
        {
                alert("bam")
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    Each inputted character causes an alert window:<input type="text" onkeyup="popup()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this as designed or is this a problem? How do you prevent FireFox from firing again?

EDIT: I found it [on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112298), does bugzilla have a "vote-up" or equivalent feature? This through me astray when trying to trouble shoot and I was looking for infinite loop/recursion in the function that was being called.

Comment: Personally I would consider that a bug. You can look through the (massive) Bugzilla database or just log a clear bug on it.

Comment: What if you change the focus away from the input before the alert. Does that stop the unwanted behaviour?

Comment: If you use **onkeypress** in your example, both browsers fire once for a character input, and not when you press enter in the modal alert. I can't imagine needing to worry about it- alerts, confirms and prompts are mostly in the rear view window, aside from a huge base of old tutorials.

Comment: @TimBJames yes it does using `blur()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Firefox destroys its alerts much more quickly than other browsers, and it's possible for the focus to return to your field while the Enter key is still down. It's possible to reproduce this in other browsers by holding the Enter key down a bit longer.